# QMutex with QConcurrent::run not working as expected?

Tags: c++, qt, opencv, qtconcurrent, qmutex

I am making a Qt GUI application that uses a custom `QLabel` class (name as `ImageInteraction`) to show images from a streaming camera while also allowing mouse interaction on the image. As the GUI has other functionalities, the customized QLabel class does the job of extracting the image from the camera and updating its shown image through a `while` loop in a function which is run in another thread. The code for that is as below:

```
void ImageInteraction::startVideo()
{
    if (!capture.open(streamUrl))
    {
        QMessageBox::warning(this, "Error", "No input device availabe!");
    }
    else
    {
        QFuture<void> multiprocess = QtConcurrent::run(this, &ImageInteraction::loadVideo);
    }
}

void ImageInteraction::loadVideo()
{
    while(loopContinue){
    cv::Mat frame;
    capture.read(frame);
    if(!frame.empty())
    {
        cv::cvtColor(frame, frame, CV_BGR2RGBA);
        cv::resize(frame, frame, cv::Size(this->width(), this->height()), 0, 0);
        QImage image(frame.data, frame.cols, frame.rows, frame.step, QImage::Format_RGBA8888);
                this->setPixmap(QPixmap::fromImage(image));
            }
    }
    capture.release();
 }
```

Here `capture` is of type `cv::VideoCapture` and `loopContinue` is a boolean type which is initially set to be `true`. There is a `closeEvent()` function that invokes the method for stopping the capture of the image from the camera.

```
void MainWindow::closeEvent(QCloseEvent *event)
{
    liveVideo->stopVideoThread();//liveVideo is a pointer to an object of ImageInteraction
    event->accept();
}
```

where `stopVideoThread` simply sets the boolean flag `loopContinue` to `false` and has the following simple code:

```
void ImageInteraction::stopVideoThread()
{
    mutex.lock();//QMutex mutex;
    loopContinue = false;
    mutex.unlock();
}
```

In my understanding the `while` loop in `loadVideo` method should be stopped once `stopVideoThread` method is invoked and `loopContinue` is set to false. But in reality, when the close button is pressed, apparently it doesn't stop `while` loop and the application crashes with a message:

```
The inferior stopped because it received a signal from the operating system.

Signal name : SIGSEGV
Signal meaning : Segmentation fault
```

Am I using `QtConcurrent::run` method and the `QMutex` object erroneously? Could you identify what the problem is? FYI, the OS is ubuntu 14.04 and IDE is QtCreator.

Thanks!

Comment: You're locking `mutex` in `stopVideoThread` but there is no corresponding lock in `loadVideo`. I would suggest using [std::atomic](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/atomic/atomic) here instead.

Comment: I would also suggest running your application under a debugger to get a better idea as to why your app crashes.

Comment: @MohamadElghawi It crashes because the pointer to object of `ImageInteraction` is deleted in one thread whereas in the other thread `cv::VideoCapture capture`(which is a member of `ImageInteraction` itself) is being tried to access. If I'm indeed locking `mutex` in `stopVideoThread` without having any corresponding lock in `loadVideo`, then how do I make the correspondence? I tried with `std::atomic`, it didn't solve my problem.

Comment: You need to make sure that your thread has shutdown before destroying the `ImageInteraction` instance. Try calling `multiprocess.waitForFinished()` in the destructor of `ImageInteraction`.

Comment: Using `std::atomic` will not solve your issue but it's much cleaner than using a `mutex` in this particular situation and can even be lock-free.

Comment: @MohamadElghawi I tried using `std::atomic`, but it wasn't working, may be I'm not doing the right way, could you please post an example based on the code I've put to show how I can use it? In the meantime, I have used `QThreadPool::globalInstance()->activeThreadCount()` and `QThreadPool::globalInstance()->waitForDone()` and managed to finally close the application without any crash.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following is just an idea of the improvements mentioned in the above comments.

```
class ImageInteraction
{
public:
    ~ImageInteraction()
    {
        multiprocess_.waitForFinished();
    }

    void startVideo()
    {
        if (!capture.open(streamUrl))
        {
            QMessageBox::warning(this, "Error", "No input device availabe!");
        }
        else
        {
            multiprocess_ = QtConcurrent::run(this, &ImageInteraction::loadVideo);
        }
    }

    void loadVideo()
    {
        while(loopContinue_)
        {
            cv::Mat frame;
            capture.read(frame);
            if(!frame.empty())
            {
                cv::cvtColor(frame, frame, CV_BGR2RGBA);
                cv::resize(frame, frame, cv::Size(this->width(), this->height()), 0, 0);
                QImage image(frame.data, frame.cols, frame.rows, frame.step, QImage::Format_RGBA8888);
                this->setPixmap(QPixmap::fromImage(image));
            }
        }
        capture.release();
    }

    void stopVideoThread()
    {
        loopContinue_ = false;
        //multiprocess_.waitForFinished(); // you can call this here if you want to make sure that the thread has finished before returning
    }

private:
    QFuture<void> multiprocess_;
    std::atomic<bool> loopContinue_;
};
```

Comment: Thanks! Although `QThreadPool::globalInstance()->activeThreadCount()` and `QThreadPool::globalInstance()->waitForDone()` did the job for me, this answer also validly solves my problem.